# Time Series Descriptive Stats by groups in R

Tags: r, grouping

I am trying to get a table of groupwise descriptive stats (number of observations, Mean, SD, Kurtosis, skewness), specifically for one variable(daily_return), from a time series data-frame that includes multiple groups. I am interested in getting the descriptive stats for ranknow < 21, data as follows:

---

Symbol     Name     Ranknow      N     Mean    Sd   Kurtosis

---

My data frame has the below structure:

Slug    symbol name date ranknow close spread  daily_returns

Comment: Welcome to SO! This community has a few [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [norms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and following them will help you get a good answer to your question. In particular, it's best to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example). Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4573108) for tips regarding R-specific MCVEs. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use the subset function where ranknow <21 
df <- df[ which(ranknow < 21, ]
then run summary(df)
also run kurtosis(df) and skewness(df) *both of these are part of the moments package.

Comment: Hi Sarah,

Thanks a lot for your reply. I have multiple columns in the dataframe and I need to get the groupwise ( rankwise) summary of  a specific column. 

The dataframe contains :
Slug  symbol   name    date    ranknow   close     spread     daily_returns ...

I want the output to be :
Symbol  Name     Ranknow     N      Mean      Sd      Kurtosis ....

Hope this helps.